# Cannot get TopologicalSorter from graphlib

Tags: python, importerror

I did

```
pip3 install graphlib
```

I can now `import graphlib`, but

```
from graphlib import TopologicalSorter
```

fails. If I `import graphlib`, it tells me that there is no attibute `TopologicalSorter`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confusingly, `graphlib` on PyPI is not the real `graphlib`, so you don’t have the right package installed.

You need to replace `graphlib`’s evil twin with the real thing:

```
pip3 uninstall graphlib
pip3 install graphlib-backport
```